# Dynamically change the mask for the selected bytes

Tags: c#, .net, byte, bit, bitmask

Say for example I have a hex `1F40` = `8000`, I want to show it in a textbox as 
`1111.1111.1111.1111`, because I dont want to hide/mask any part of it. The user should be allowed to change that if they wish. Like `1111.1111.0000.1111` = `7936` for example if they wanted to.
Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A mask for `1F40` would be `1111.1111.1111.1111` - is that what you meant?

Comment: Indeed, just changed it aswel when I realized

Comment: So according to your example, if they changed it from 1 to 0 what would the new hex value be?

Comment: I changed it since the original example did no change much

Comment: It's certainly possible and would be easier without the decimal points and you would have to make sure there was always 16 binary digits. Then you could just use one of the convert functions.

Comment: I wanted to start of simple, but the messages I want to mask could be between 8 and 58 binary digits if I remember correcly.